# Use System.Text.Json to deserialize properties with private setters

Tags: c#, serialization, system.text.json

Is there a way to use **System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize** with object that contains private setters properties, and fill those properties? (like **Newtonsoft.Json** does)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In .NET Core 3.x, that is not possible. In .NET 5 timeline, [support has been added](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/34675).

Comment: Beware though if you use JsonInclude-trickery to serialize lists: If the getter is public, you can also read-/write-access individual elements, if no further trickery is used.

Comment: Looks like newtonsoft is still on the table, having to go through all this trickery just to substitute "it just works" behavior is getting old at this point :/

Answer (score 41):

As per [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-immutability) (C# 9), you got 2 options:

1. Use `init` instead of `set` on the property. E.g. `public string Summary { get; init; }`
2. Add `JsonInclude` attribute on the properties with private setters. E.g.

   ```
   [JsonInclude] 
   public string Summary { get; private set; }
   ```

A bonus option (starting from .NET 5) would be handling `private` fields by either adding the same `JsonInclude` attribute ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.includefields)) or setting `JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields` option ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#include-fields)). Would it be ideologically correct is a different question...

Either way, [JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#deserialize-from-utf-8) will do it for you.

Comment: Indeed, `init` it's a powerful concept and will do the job gracefully in such like situations. `[JsonInclude]` it is what i was looking for, but it is only available in .NET 5.

Comment: Beware though if you use JsonInclude-trickery to serialize lists: If the getter is public, you can also read-/write-access individual elements, if no further trickery is used.

Comment: what about support for `private readonly` *fields*?

Comment: It's a fair comment. Thanks @JobaDiniz. Yes, it's possible, I updated the answer.

Comment: Your remark about `JsonInclude` is not correct, sadly. "When applied to a property, indicates that non-public getters and setters can be used for serialization and deserialization. Non-public properties are not supported."

Comment: @greenoldman, not sure where the message you're quoting is coming from. [Here's an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/immutability?pivots=dotnet-6-0#non-public-property-accessors) from Microsoft for "_Non-public property accessors_" that shows the trick for `[JsonInclude]`

Comment: @AlexKlaus The quote comes from the linked docs. Sadly for me, MS make a difference between private member and public member with private access.